# TextView Centralize text to the background image

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I having background image for the textview.I want the text to be center in that image,But it showing on the left top corner.Please help me.

Text view showing like this..

[image: Previous View]

But i want it to be..!
[image]
[I want to be centeralize to the background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqMRu.png)

Comment: put your relevant xml code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [android:gravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3agravity) attribute

`android:gravity="center_vertical"` should do the case here...

Comment: But in OP's case, background will float in center too.

Comment: @singularity I don't understand. How does `gravity` will affect the parent background??

Comment: @RKN not parent's background, but `TextView`'s, as OP has the background on the `TextView`.

Comment: @singularity Ya, but giving `android:gravity` will only the center the text inside `TextView`

Answer (score 1):

try to set gravity to center of your linear layout